# Supremum of log(E[X]]-E[log(X)]

Tags: pr.probability, calculus-of-variations

I've been tackling some questions on probability theory and got stuck on this one.

Determine $$\sup_{1≤X≤b} \ \log(E[X])-E[\log(X)]$$ where $X$ is a random variable defined in $[1,b]$. In other words, it means finding the greatest value of the difference amongst **all** random variables defined on the interval.

Using the definition of [Shannon Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy), I've been able to rewrite the equation to:
$$ \sup_{1≤X≤b} \ \ \log(E[X]) + H[X]$$
alternatively,
$$ \sup_{1≤X≤b} \ \ H[X]-\log(\frac{1}{E[X]})  $$

Using Jensen's Inequality, we find that the difference is always positive because $\log$ is a concave function.

At first I tried to derivate with respect to $X$ in order to find a differential equation but it was fruitless. So, I thought the best approach would be maximizing using Lagrange Multiplier but couldn't find a proper functional due to the presence of the term $\log(E[X])$.

Comment: Hint: It is not a variational calculus problem. The supremum is attained at a r.v. $X$ taking just two values: $1$ and $b$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Is it just a 'stretched' Bernoulli with an optimal parameter p?

Comment: Yes, you can call it this way, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log$ is strictly concave, $\log(t) \ge (t-1)(\log b)/(b-1)$ for $t$ in $[1,b]$ with equality only at the endpoints. (The RHS is the straight line that agrees with $\log$ at $1$ and at $b$.) Thus for any random variable $X$ taking values in $[1,b]$ we have $E[\log X] \ge (E[X]-1)(\log b)/(b-1)$ with equality only if $P[X \in \{1,b\}]=1$. So the supremum in the original question is attained only for $X$ that takes these two values (as noted in Fedja's comment). For such $X$ let $p=P[X=b]$. Then $\log(E[X])-E[\log X]=\log(pb-p+1)-p\log(b)$. Denoting the RHS by $f_b(p)$, we see that $f_b$ is strictly concave in $[0,1]$ and vanishes at $0,1$. So its maximum is attained at the unique $p$ where $f_b'(p)=0$ namely $p=(b-1-\log b)/(b-1)$. Set $p$ to this value. The supremum in the original problem thus equals $f_b(p)=\log(b-\log b)-(b-1-\log b)(\log b)/(b-1)$.

Comment: Antonio, can you accept the answer so your question will be marked as answered?